# Prooving {c1v1,...,cnvn} for all c nonzero a basis for V.

Tags: linear-algebra

I just want to know the structure of the proof regarding this.

Let $V$ be a vector space in F and let $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ be a basis for $V$. Prove that of $c_1, ... , c_n$ are all non-zero, then $\{c_1v_1,...,c_nv_n\}$ is also a basis for $V$.

Comment: Um, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A corollary of the replacement theorem says that if a finite dimensional vector space has a basis $\beta$ consisting of $n$ elements, i.e., $\text{dim}V=n$, then every other basis of the same vector space has $n$ number of elements.

So, if you're given that $\beta=\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a basis of $V(F)$ and $c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n\in F\setminus\{0\}$ where $0$ denotes the zero element of $F$, then it suffices to show that $\gamma=\{c_1v_1,c_2v_2,\ldots,c_nv_n\}=\{c_iv_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is linearly independent to prove that it is a basis of $V$.

Since $\beta$ is a basis of $V$, so $\beta$ is linearly independent. So, if $\alpha_i\in F~\forall~1\leq i\leq n$, then,

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_iv_i=0_V\implies \alpha_i=0~\forall~1\leq i\leq n\tag 1$$

Now, consider the sum $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\delta_ic_iv_i=0_V$ where $\delta_i\in F~\forall~1\leq i\leq n$.

Using $(1)$ on the sum considered above, you get that we should have $\delta_ic_i=0~\forall~1\leq i\leq n$. But note that $c_i\neq 0~\forall~1\leq i\leq n$. It follows from the zero product property that $\delta_i=0~\forall~1\leq i\leq n$ and hence the set $\{c_iv_i\}_{i=1}^n=\gamma$ is linearly independent.

It follows from the corollary mentioned in the beginning of the answer that $\gamma$ is also a basis of $V$ and we're done. $_\square$

**Note:**  $0_V$ is used to denote the zero vector of $V$.

Comment: thanks a lot.  It has been clarified me considering the scalar as a product of ci's and another one. I used earlier but I'm just not sur if it is correct... Thumbs up

Comment: @Zurchi, glad that the answer helped ya. :)

Answer (score 1):

For any $v\in V$
$$v=\sum_n a_n v_n =\sum_n \frac{a_n}{c_n} c_nv_n $$
thus $$V=Span \{v_1,...,v_n\} = Span \{c_1 v_1,...,c_nv_n\}$$
and therefore $\{c_1 v_1,...,c_nv_n\}$ is a basis of $V$.